# .repeater controller in jquery

Tags: jquery, json, jquery.repeater

My code was correct however the file doesn't diplay in the ui.

```html
<div id="sec-feature-modules" class="accordion my-5">
</div>
```

```js
$("#sec-feature-modules").repeater({
  endpoint: "/content/files/features.json",
  mappingFunction: (features) => features.modules,
  messageNoResult:
    "Sorry, there are no modules available at this time. Please check back later.",
  cssClassNoResult: "empty",
});
```

Comment: Even if you had an actual question it's going to be very difficult for anyone to help as the code provided is very far from a [mre].  You need to provide code that someone can run that demonstrates the issue you're encountering.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide an example of the `features.json` contents. Also, check your browser's dev-tools _Console_ panel for errors and add them to your question, if any

Comment: *the file doesn't diplay in the ui* - should it? why?  There doesn't appear to be any features [tag:jquery.repeater] in the *very* limited documentation that I could quickly find that states you get an file previews.   Otherwise, it's unclear what "the file doesn't display" actually means - Are you expecting a preview? Are you expecting to see a file after you POST your form?